# KNeighborsClassifier .fit method returns "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Tags: python, knn, ambiguous, valueerror

I have read numerous Q&A on the subject title; however, I am having a hard time understanding why the ambiguous truth value error is raised when I use the KNeighborsClassifier .fit method. The code and the data that I have is relatively straightforward:

> First, I drop all nan values along the row axis from the Opt_Data dataframe and assign the results to the variable titled Training_Data.

```
Training_Data = Opt_Data.dropna(axis=0,how='any')
```

[Screenshot of the sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s6ER.png)

> Next, I create two numpy arrays from the Training_Data dataframe. The X_Train array consists of data from Columns 1 - 10 and the Y_Train array consists of data from the Target Column. In the code below, the variable name *question* is the column name of the Target Column.

```
X_Train = np.array(Training_Data.loc[:,Training_Data.columns != question])

Y_Train = np.array(Training_Data[question])
```

> After creating my arrays, I set up my KNeighborsClassifier function and pass the results to the variable titled *knn*. The variable *opt_neighbors* is an integer value (29). When I use the .fit method on knn, I get the aforementioned value error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=opt_neighbors,weights='distance',metric='hamming')

knn.fit(X_Train,Y_Train)
```

The shape of the actual X_Train array is (1783,10) and the shape of the actual Y_Train array is (1783,).

I read a blog that stated duplicate rows could be the cause for this error.  However, when I used the drop_duplicates method on the Training_Data dataframe and executed the same code, I received the same error message.

I also read that "The *or* and *and* python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" | (or) or & (and) operations." However, I am not sure how this statement applies as I am not using *or* or *and* statements explicitly.

I greatly appreciate any help that anyone can offer me. Thank you!

Comment: never provide screenshots of data; paste the data. that said, just use `Traning_data.loc[:,Training_data.columns != 'Target column' ]`. not sure if question = 'Target column'? also, when you slice by loc, it will yield an ndarray. you need not cast it into one.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this method. It would be helpful if you could explain how to paste tables from excel without losing the formatting. This is all I could find: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: The 'question' variable is the actual column name of the Target Column.  For example, if the Target Column is "What did you have for breakfast?", then the 'question' variable is the string 'What did you have for breakfast?"

Answer (score 1):

There was a portion of my code that I thought was irrelevant to the problem; however, as it turns out it is what was causing the problem:

> In the code below, I am assigning an element from a dataframe (Opt_report) to the variable *opt_neighbors*.  I thought this assignment would create a scalar value, however, it is a pandas Series that consists of an index number (135) and the integer value (19).  When I pass this variable to the n_neighbors argument in the KNeighborsClassifier function, it is understood as the Series 135  19.0 as shown in Out [3] line 2, n_neighbors = 135  19.0.  My KNeighborsClassifier was poorly executed, which led to the .fit method of the KNeighborsClassifier not working properly.

```
In  [1]:  opt_neighbors = Opt_report['Optimal_Neighbors']
Out [1]:  135 19.0
          Name: Optimal_Neighbors, dtype: float64

In  [2]: type(opt_neighbors)
Out [2]: pandas.core.series.Series

In  [3]: knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=opt_neighbors,weights='distance',metric='hamming')
         knn
Out [3]: KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='hamming', metric_params=None, n_jobs=1,
         n_neighbors=135    19.0
         Name: Optimal_Neighbors, dtype: float64,p=2, weights='distance')
```

> Updating the code as shown below fixes this problem.

```
In  [4]: opt_neighbors = int(Opt_report['Optimal_Neighbors'])
Out [4]: 19
```